# AS3 Regexp Do not include?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, include

I have a Regex in AS3. Until now it's been working, but now I would like to disclude a phrase from the beginning. Specifically, the original was:

```
var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp(keyword,'/gi');
```

I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

```
var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp(!'<a href=\"event:' + keyword,'/gi');
```

Where

```
baaah
```

would work, but

```
<ahref="event:baaah
```

would NOT work.

Please help! What is the proper syntax to implement in my code.

Comment: What I want to do is replace things within a larger string with my regex. In your regex you had /(?<=<a href='event:).+/, where . can match anything. However, I want it to only match a String named keyword. Keyword is dynamic, so I cannot type a specific thing. The regex must be the keyword String but only if it is NOT preceeded by '<a href="event:'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this follows.

```
var myPattern:RegExp = /(?<=<a href='event:).+/;   
var str:String = "<a href='event:baaah";
var result:Array = myPattern.exec(str);
trace(result[0]); //baaah
```

---

I strongly recommend : [Regular_expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

**`Assertions`**

```
 - foo(?=bar)   Lookahead assertion. The pattern foo will only match if
   followed by a match of pattern bar.

 - foo(?!bar)   Negative lookahead assertion. The pattern foo will only
   match if not followed by a match of pattern bar.

 - (?<=foo)bar  Lookbehind assertion. The pattern bar will only match if
   preceeded by a match of pattern foo.

 - (?<!foo)bar  Negative lookbehind assertion. The pattern bar will only
   match if not preceeded by a match of pattern foo.
```

Comment: What I want to do is replace things within a larger string with my regex. In your regex you had /(?<=<a href='event:).+/, where . can match anything. However, I want it to only match a String named keyword. Keyword is dynamic, so I cannot type a specific thing. The regex must be the keyword String but only if it is NOT preceeded by '<a href="event:'. I checked out wikipedia, and I understand regex to a certain extent. But what I'm asking is specific and shouldn't be that complicated. Thank you for your in depth answer anyhow! If you could clarify toward what I just mentioned, that'd be great!!